# Does cmpxchg call provided by linux ever crash?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, kernel

I am using cmpxchg() provided by linux kernel (SLES11-SP2)
Its panicking.
the exact point its crashing is in line 2005:

```
            if (cmpxchg(var, old, new) == old)
2002:       48 89 d8                mov    %rbx,%rax
2005:       f0 4d 0f b1 34 24       lock cmpxchg %r14,(%r12)
200b:       48 39 c3                cmp    %rax,%rbx
200e:       74 27                   je     2037 <atomicPatchFnPtr+0x77>
```

Any clue about, how I can go about debugging ?Is this happening due to race condition in locking a variable?
Or do i need to post this as a bug on kernel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock cmpxchg instruction can cause an access violation if the address it is passed (in %r12 here) is invalid. That is probably the variable var in the line of code above. It suggests that var is pointing to some invalid memory. It isn't a race in the cmpxchg function, but it might still be a race condition in the calling function.